# Using inheritance to add an ID field for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-6, primary-key

I would save an object in a databse using Entity Framework 6.
I cannot add an ID field to this objct, so I've though to add a key field via inheritance, this way:

```
public base_class() 
{
  public int field1 { get; set; }
  public int field2 { get; set; }
}

public entity_obj() : base_class() 
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}
```

The dbContext.Add() method always throws a System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null'. I've tried a lot of solutions for this error but the exception persists.

Is this method, based on inheritance, correct or could be it the core of the problem?

This is the exception text:

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName) in C:\mc\ef6-6.4.4\src\Common\Check.cs:line 19
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.EntitySetMapping..ctor(EntitySet entitySet, EntityContainerMapping containerMapping) in C:\mc\ef6-6.4.4\src\EntityFramework\Core\Mapping\EntitySetMapping.cs:line 45
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.AddEntitySetMapping(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntitySet entitySet) in C:\mc\ef6-6.4.4\src\EntityFramework\ModelConfiguration\Edm\DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.cs:line 219
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.TableMappingGenerator.Generate(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping) in C:\mc\ef6-6.4.4\src\EntityFramework\ModelConfiguration\Edm\Services\TableMappingGenerator.cs:line 26
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping) in C:\mc\ef6-6.4.4\src\EntityFramework\ModelConfiguration\Edm\Services\DatabaseMappingGenerator.cs:line 71
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel conceptualModel) in C:\mc\ef6-6.4.4\src\EntityFramework\ModelConfiguration\Edm\Services\DatabaseMappingGenerator.cs:line 42
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.GenerateDatabaseMapping(EdmModel model, DbProviderInfo providerInfo, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) in C:\mc\ef6-6.4.4\src\EntityFramework\ModelConfiguration\Edm\EdmModelExtensions.cs:line 178
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo) in C:\mc\ef6-6.4.4\src\EntityFramework\DbModelBuilder.cs:line 421
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) in C:\mc\ef6-6.4.4\src\EntityFramework\DbModelBuilder.cs:line 365
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) in C:\mc\ef6-6.4.4\src\EntityFramework\Internal\LazyInternalContext.cs:line 509
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) in C:\mc\ef6-6.4.4\src\EntityFramework\Internal\RetryLazy`.cs:line 63
```

Comment: `I cannot add an ID field to this object` in fact, you are adding an ID to this object. One that's private and probably never set, so it's 0 by default, not null. Post your actual code and actual full exception string, not just a part of the message. What's your entity class? `base_class` or `entity_obj` ?

Comment: entity_obj is entity class. base_class is produced by a swagger definition used for reading an API. It's enough complex to publish, sorry. The complete message for exception is ' System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet' '. The stacktrace contains errors from EntityFramework code that I'm trying to debug.

Comment: It's not that complex. A *lot* of API projects use DTOs and ORMs. Post the full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()` instead of describing it. Post the classes and the DbContext configuration. If you search SO, you'll see that most EF questions contain these things

Comment: You can get the full exception text by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup in Visual Studio

Comment: `produced by a swagger definition` that's your API DTO, not your database entity. Nothing forces you to use one as the other, although you can, up to a point. Many applications use separate types for the API and database DTOs, mapping between them with AutoMapper. That's a tool that can map objects based on type names and a few conventions. This way you won't have to change your database every time the remote API changes

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos, this is the current exception content

[basic links] https://pastebin.com/raw/2hs8CKDX

The complexity is due to privacy :). I hope to be more clear: base_class comes from an API. entity_obj is for entity. I know I can use it, but I prefer to not use base class for entity.

Comment: Add the code and exception text as text in the question itself. No, there are no privacy concerns. Code that's used by every single ASP.NET Core developer isn't neither a privacy nor a copyright concern